# Many to Many Relationship BY DATE in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to be able to calculate a measure in a table of many to many relationship.  Here are my two tables:

Contracts Table

```
Serial#  ContractTyp  StartDate    EndDate
A        MP           1/1/2017    1/6/2018
B        ML           10/24/2017  6/30/2020
A        ML           1/6/2018    12/30/2019
C        MU           5/15/2018   1/1/2021
```

Performance Table

```
Serial#  Diff  Good  Bad  Date
A        15    1     0    1/30/2017
B        -24   1     0    12/17/2017
A        57    0     1    4/22/2017
A        18    1     0    2/1/2018
C        123   0     1    9/12/2018
```

So, my measure is simple. It just calculates the percentage of Good by Serial#.

```
NUM_GOOD = CALCULATE(COUNTA('Performance'[Good]),'Performance[Good] IN {"1"})
NUM_BAD = CALCULATE(COUNTA('Performance'[Bad]),'Performance[Bad] IN {"1"})
PERFORMANCE_METRIC = NUM_GOOD/(NUM_BAD + NUM_GOOD)
```

I need to be able to run that performance metric for every Serial# but only for when the machines were under a MP or MU ContractTyp.  So I need it to be able to look at the Date in the Performance Table and make sure that date falls in the range between StartDate and EndDate on the Contracts Table where Serial# is MP or MU.

So I for example if I want to look at the Performance of all Serial#'s with a ContractTyp of MP or MU in the last 2 years I would want the result to look as follows:

```
Serial#  PERFORMANCE_METRIC
A        50%
B        100%
C        0%
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After thinking about it over night, I'm thinking I just need to be able to filter my Performance Table down to the rows that I need. SO I think I need a calculated column in my Performance Table that is TRUE when the Date is within the date range of StartDate and EndDate when the ContractTyp is MP or MU. It sounds so simple in theory, but I'm really struggling...

Comment: how do you know in performance table the type of contract? date relationship would not help much in this case

Comment: The measure or custom column would have to reference the start and end date in the Contracts table by the Date in the Performance Table. (IE: For Serial# (If Performance[Date] >= Contracts[StartDate] AND Performance[Date] <= Contracts[EndDate] AND Contracts[ContractType] IN {MP, MU} ) TRUE else FALSE)

Comment: It is painful to see a many-to-many relationship in this scenario. Please re-think your data model. Please not add calculated columns and enrich your data source instead. For example, you could add in the data source of contracts table the [Good] and [Bad] attributes and calculate the Measure only using Contracts. Other approaches would use physical relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a formula for a Calculated Column that you could add to the Performance table to return the True / False values (ref your comments).

To explain the logic:

1. Store the Serial and Date values (from the current record) in variables.
2. If we find at least 1 matching Contract with the required ContractTyp and Date range, return True, otherwise False.

```
Has Contract =
VAR vSerial = [Serial#]
VAR vDate = [Date]
RETURN
    IF (
        CALCULATE (
            COUNTROWS ( Contracts ),
            Contracts[Serial#] = vSerial,
            Contracts[ContractTyp] IN { "MP", "MU" },
            Contracts[StartDate] <= vDate,
            Contracts[EndDate] >= vDate
        ) > 0,
        TRUE (),
        FALSE ()
    )
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create a new table in Power BI by converting the Contracts table which is at a Serial #, Start date and End date level to a Serial # and Date level. For example if the data has the following records:

```
ID Type Start      End

1  MP    1/1/2019  1/2/2019
```

You should convert it into something like this:

```
ID Type Date

1 MP 1/1/2019

1 MP 1/2/2019
```

The following link should help you out regarding this:

https://natechamberlain.com/2018/08/08/how-to-add-rows-for-dates-between-start-and-end-dates-in-power-bi-date-range-data/

Once the table is converted, you should be able to do a simple join based on Serial# and date and it will be a one to one relationship. Then you can apply whatever filter you are looking for.

One caveat here is that, the size of the data would matter a lot. If the Contracts table has a reasonable number of records, this would work, otherwise the data might blow up.

Comment: Are you saying create a new row for every date between start date and end date?

Comment: It is over 180,000 machines long. Each machine potentially having multiple revisions to the contract. In this case I don't think that method would be feasible. Certainly a good idea though

Comment: It also depends by the time granularity you need, if it is 1 a year or 1 per day. In general, if you uave very simple aggregation with no filter, DAX engine easily manage Billions of rows. Instead, if you apply a complex filter such as '>', '<' even on a small table it would be slow.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another possible answer using merge queries. Instead of creating a relationship you can directly merge the two tables. If you have not done this before, you can access this is in the edit query window. Once you merge both the tables using serial ID as the key, you can use a formula like below to use as a filter:

```
Filter Field = IF(Date2[Date]>=Date2[Date1.Start]&&Date2[Date]<=Date2[Date1.End],1,0)
```

Then you can simply set Filter Field =1 in the filter pane and you should be good to go. Hope this helps.

Here is a tutorial on merge queries. The link is specifically for excel, but it should work in power bi as well:

https://www.powerquery.training/merge-tables/

Comment: Answer the question by also showing how you would address the calculation.